# SELECT related articles based on keywords from single table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am working on a web project which shows article details on one of it pages and on side i also need to show top 5 related article based on `keywords` or `tags`.

I am not sure how i can entirely do it using T-SQL rather than doing part of processing from code behind.

I using FUNCTION to split my keywords and pass results to other query to get desired result which is not working for me.

```
CREATE TABLE Article
(
 ArticleID int,
 Title varchar(200),
 Description varchar(500),
 Details nvarchar(MAX),
 keywords varchar(100)
 )

INSERT INTO Article VALUES(1, 'Article One','Article desc', 'article details', 'one,two,three')
INSERT INTO Article VALUES(2, 'Article Two','Article desc', 'article details', 'two,three,four')
INSERT INTO Article VALUES(3, 'Article three','Article desc', 'article details', 'three,four,five')
INSERT INTO Article VALUES(4, 'Article four','Article desc', 'article details', ',four,five,six')
INSERT INTO Article VALUES(5, 'Article five','Article desc', 'article details', 'two,three')
INSERT INTO Article VALUES(6, 'Article six','Article desc', 'article details', 'eight, nine')
INSERT INTO Article VALUES(7, 'Article six','Article desc', 'article details', 'ten, nine')
INSERT INTO Article VALUES(8, 'Article six','Article desc', 'article details', 'eleven, eight')
```

FUNCTION

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[uf_SplitKeywords] 
   (  @DELIMITER VARCHAR(5), 
      @LIST      VARCHAR(MAX) 
   ) 
   RETURNS @TABLEOFVALUES TABLE 
      (  ROWID   SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1), 
         [VALUE] VARCHAR(MAX) 
      ) 
AS 
   BEGIN

      DECLARE @LENSTRING INT 

      WHILE LEN( @LIST ) > 0 
         BEGIN 

            SELECT @LENSTRING = 
               (CASE CHARINDEX( @DELIMITER, @LIST ) 
                   WHEN 0 THEN LEN( @LIST ) 
                   ELSE ( CHARINDEX( @DELIMITER, @LIST ) -1 )
                END
               ) 

            INSERT INTO @TABLEOFVALUES 
               SELECT SUBSTRING( @LIST, 1, @LENSTRING )

            SELECT @LIST = 
               (CASE ( LEN( @LIST ) - @LENSTRING ) 
                   WHEN 0 THEN '' 
                   ELSE RIGHT( @LIST, LEN( @LIST ) - @LENSTRING - 1 ) 
                END
               ) 
         END

      RETURN 

   END
```

**What i need?**

Show article with id 3

```
SELECT ArticleID, Title, Keywords FROM Article WHERE ArticleID = 3
```

Then i need to show related article based on keywords `three,four,five`
From selected article as in this case should be article with `articleid=3`
 in this case result should show me article with id 1,2,3,4,5 as keywords match with these rows only.

I am trying to achieve this with following query which is not working

```
SELECT TOP 5 ArticleID, Title, Keywords FROM Articles WHERE Keywords IN
(SELECT '''%'+ VALUE+ '%''' AS VALUE FROM [uf_SplitKeywords] (',', 'one,two,three'))
```

I would appreciate help in this regard.

Sample on [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5836f) for some reason i am not able to create FUNCTION which i have mentioned above on sqlFiddle.

Comment: Possible solution could be with CTE QUERY but i am not sure how to split keywords  which as separated by `,`. Any such solution is appreciated

Comment: You should not keep keywords as a comma-separated string in a text field. You have a relational database system, make a relation for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Alter FUNCTION [dbo].[uf_SplitKeywords] 
   (  @DELIMITER VARCHAR(5), 
      @LIST      VARCHAR(MAX) 
   ) 
   RETURNS @TABLEOFVALUES TABLE 
      (  ROWID   int IDENTITY(1,1), 
         [VALUE] VARCHAR(MAX) 
      ) 
AS 
   BEGIN
   Declare @Pos int
   While LEN(@List) > 0
      begin
        Select @Pos=CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,1)      
        if @Pos>0
           begin
             Insert into @TABLEOFVALUES ([Value]) Values (SubString(@List,1,@Pos -1))
             Select @LIST = STUFF(@List,1,@Pos ,'')
           end
        else  
            begin
            Insert into @TABLEOFVALUES ([Value]) Values (@List)
            Select @LIST =''
            end  
      end
   Return 
   End
```

With call by

```
Select Distinct b.ArticleID,b.Title,b.Description,b.Details,b.KeyWords from
(
Select * from Article a1 
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[uf_SplitKeywords](',',keywords) f1
Where a1.ArticleID=3
) a
Join
(
Select * from Article a2 
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[uf_SplitKeywords](',',keywords) f2
) b
on a.Value=b.Value
```

Comment: Thanks by this time i had also found the solution by fixing my function. I tried your solution also it works fine & get me same result which my solution is giving me. I will mark your question as correct since it gives me the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have an article with a "keyword" and "tags". You want to show related articles with same "keyword" or "tags".

Conceptually you need to modify the design of your database tables. Instead of inserting Keywords as a varchar(100) in the Article table, you can create a new table Article_Keywords
with ArticleID int as Foreign Key constraint and another column Keywords as varchar.

Then you can join the tables based on article ID. So Article_Keywords would look like:

### Best Practice Solution

### Dont allow Nulls on ID Columns

```
alter TABLE Article
alter column ArticleID int not null
```

### Add Primary Key to ID columns for Indexing and Joining with other tables

```
alter TABLE Article
add constraint PK_ArticleID PRIMARY KEY (ArticleID)
```

### Create New table Article Keywords

```
create table Article_Keywords
(
    [ArticleID] int not null,
    [Keywords] nvarchar(100),
    Foreign key ([ArticleID]) References Article(ArticleID),
)
```

### INSERT Data

```
insert into [Article_Keywords] Values (1,'one'),(1,'two'),(1,'three');
insert into [Article_Keywords] Values (2,'two'),(2,'three'),(2,'four');
insert into [Article_Keywords] Values (3,'three'),(3,'four'),(3,'five');
insert into [Article_Keywords] Values (4,'four'),(4,'five'),(4,'six'),(5,'two'),(5,'three'),(6,'eight'),(6,'nine'),(7,'nine'),(7,'ten'),(8,'eleven');

delete from Article_Keywords where [ArticleID] = [Keywords]

SELECT
    DISTINCT AK1.ArticleID
FROM Article_Keywords AK1
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT AK2.Keywords from Article_Keywords AK2
WHERE AK2.[ArticleID] = 3 AND AK1.[KEYWORDS] = AK2.[KEYWORDS]
)
```

### However, if you feel the need to go down the way you are going, you could use a cursor (unadvisable):

Create a temporary table to store all Related articles

```
IF ( OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#RelatedArticles') IS NOT NULL ) DROP TABLE #RelatedArticles
CREATE TABLE #RelatedArticles (
    ArticleID int
);


DECLARE @VALUE NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE Keyword_Cursor Cursor For
```

### Use the [uf_SplitKeywords] to extract the keywords from the Article table

```
SELECT [Value] FROM [uf_SplitKeywords] (',',(SELECT [KEYWORDS] FROM ARTICLE WHERE ARTICLEID = 3))

OPEN Keyword_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Keyword_Cursor into @VALUE

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    insert into #RelatedArticles
    SELECT [ArticleID] from Article
    where [keywords] like (SELECT '%' + @VALUE +  '%');

    FETCH NEXT FROM Keyword_Cursor into @VALUE
END

CLOSE Keyword_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Keyword_Cursor

SELECT DISTINCT ArticleID from #RelatedArticles
```

Compare the two methods and you will find that having a better database design will save you a lot more time when designing for complex projects.

Comment: Completely agree with you on design, but it users who want minimal screen for update or inserting new article, So i have combined added keyword column in the same table, which made it bit difficult for me to write quert but i made it work by making some changes to the FUNCTION itself. Now it seems to get me the desired results. My ID column which usually is PK is & auto incremented. for this problem i created a sample database with dummy data, my actual table has lot many fields but for this issue fields mentioned in the question where enough. appreciate your response.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Glad to know that. As I don't know the level you are operating at, thought I would give you some value added information. Hopefully this helps! :)

Comment: `@Saidur Rehman` Appreciate your response & agree with your views without any disregard. In my case users wont enter multiple keywords multiple time either way can be to create automated process to split the keywords & use an insert statement in loop to enter multiple keywords after we save the article & trigger this code. this was user wont know what is going on in the background.Unfortunately i can accept your answer but gave you upvote for the clean solution that can be implement.