# How to combine a linq query dynamically?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Suppose I have a table, containing formatted values in a string (`nvarchar`) column. These values are supposed to be strings separated by some const symbol (let it be a semi-colon `;`). For example,

```
12;0;5;dog //four values separated by a semi-colon
```

or

```
053 //if there is only one value, no semi-colon at the end
```

The separator is always a separator, it can't be a part of the value.

I need to check if there is already a row in that table, with a list of values in that column, which contains at least one of the specified items. In other words I have a list of values:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "somevalue1", "somevalue2" };
```

the separator:

```
string separator = ";";
```

And I need to write a linq-to-sql query doing this:

```
select ... from sometable
where Value='somevalue1' or Value like 'somevalue1;%' or
      Value like '%;somevalue1' or Value like '%;somevalue1;%'

   or Value='somevalue2' or Value like 'somevalue2;%' or 
      Value like '%;somevalue2' or Value like '%;somevalue2;%'
```

It should be mentioned that any of the searched values may contain the other. That is, I may be searching for exactly `5`, while some row may contain `1;15;55`. Such row must **not** be a match. While `...;5;...` or just `5`, or `5;...`, or `...;5` are the matches.

Using linq-to sql I know how to do queries of the following kind:

```
select ... from sometable where (... or ... or ...) and (... or ...) ...
```

that is

```
IQueryable<SomeTable> query = dc.SomeTable;
foreach (string l in list)
{
    string s = l;
    query = query.Where(b => b.Value.StartsWith(s + separator) ||
                             b.Value.EndsWith(separator + s) ||
                             b.Value.Contains(separator + s + separator) ||
                             b.Value.Equals(s));
}
if (query.Any()) {/*...*/}
```

Obviously the `Where` statements are joined with `AND` in the resulting sql query, while I need `OR` everywhere.

So is there a way to get the query I need within C# code? Or the only way would be to do this with a hand-written query and [DataContext.ExecuteQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx)?

Comment: maybe you find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473380/select-related-articles-based-on-keywords-from-single-table/14474064#14474064

Comment: Although it probably can't be changed, I would like to point out that this data isn't normalized. It would be easier if instead of the semi-colon if you had a separate table with a record id and a value creating a one-to-many relationship between the record and your values thereby utilizing the features of a normalized database and making it easier to construct a query in linq. Of course, if you can't modify the table structure then I guess there isn't much you could do about it.

Comment: @LosFrijoles in general I agree with you. Definitely I had to think over extracting a separate table in the first place. However as soon as the question is already raised and it probably may take less time then redesigning this very feature completely, I'd like to know if constructing this kind of queries is possible using linq to sql at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess a `UNION` would suit your needs:

```
IQueryable<SomeTable> baseQuery = dc.SomeTable;
IQueryable<SomeTable> query = new List<SomeTable>().AsQueryable();
foreach (string l in list)
{
    string s = l;

    query.Union(baseQuery.Where(b => b.Value.StartsWith(s + separator) ||
                             b.Value.EndsWith(separator + s) ||
                             b.Value.Contains(separator + s + separator) ||
                             b.Value.Equals(s)));
}
if (query.Any()) {/*...*/}
```

Comment: Is that one database roundtrip per list element?  Or just one database roundtrip.  Hard for me to tell.

Comment: Since query and baseQuery are both IQueryable, the database roundtrip is done after the loop, when query.Any() is called. So it's only a single roundtrip.

Comment: Not familiar with linq-to-sql, can `string.StartsWith`(as well as EndsWith,Contains,Equals) be translated into correct sql statements？

Comment: I agree that the roundtrip(s) are done after the loop.  Surely, the empty list at the root of the query isn't sent into the database, so does the Queryable.Union turn into Enumerable.Union and a series of database roundtrips?  Maybe it would be better to root the query with dc.SomeTable.Where(row => 1 == 0);

Comment: Interesting thought, as my first version had exactly that root for query. But I think this is a bit cleaner. I see no reason why an IQueryable would change into an IEnumerable, whithout an explicit action.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrTheseFiltersTogether<T>(
  this IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> filters)
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> firstFilter = filters.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstFilter == null)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> alwaysTrue = x => true;
        return alwaysTrue;
    }

    var body = firstFilter.Body;
    var param = firstFilter.Parameters.ToArray();
    foreach (var nextFilter in filters.Skip(1))
    {
        var nextBody = Expression.Invoke(nextFilter, param);
        body = Expression.OrElse(body, nextBody);
    }
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
    return result;
}
```

So, you can build a List of filters easily from the input set:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "somevalue1", "somevalue2" };
List<Expression<Func<SomeTable, bool>>> equalsFilters = list
  .Select(s => row => row.Value == s).ToList();
List<Expression<Func<SomeTable, bool>>> startsWithFilters = list
  .Select(s => row => row.Value.StartsWith(s + ";")).ToList();
List<Expression<Func<SomeTable, bool>>> endsWithFilters = list
  .Select(s => row => row.Value.EndsWith(";" + s).ToList();
List<Expression<Func<SomeTable, bool>>> middleFilters = list
  .Select(s => row => row.Value.Contains(";" + s + ";")).ToList();

Expression<Func<SomeTable, bool>> theFilter = OrTheseFiltersTogether(
  equalsFilters.Concat(startsWithFilters).Concat(endsWithFilters).Concat(middleFilters)
);

query = query.Where(theFilter);
```

Comment: +1: unfortunately I am not that familiar with expressions. However I'll try to give it a try...

Comment: @Danny Chen, string.StartsWith, string.EndsWith and string.Contains are all translated into the appropriate "like" expressions by LinqToSql.  The absence of these methods from this page confirms. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882672.aspx