# LINQ - AND, ANY and NOT Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am fairly rookie with LINQ. I can do some basic stuff with it but I am in need of an expert.

I am using Entity Framework and I have a table that has 3 columns.

```
public class Aspect
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int AspectID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AspectFieldID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

I have 3 lists of words from a user's input. One contains phrases or words that must be in the `Value` field (AND), another contains phrases or words that don't have to be in the `Value` field (ANY) and the last list contains phrases or words that can not be found in the `Value` field (NOT).

I need to get every record that has all of the ALL words, any of the ANY words and none of the NOT words.

Here are my objects.

```
public class SearchAllWord
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public bool includeSynonoyms { get; set; }
}

public class SearchAnyWord
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public bool includeSynonoyms { get; set; }
}

public class SearchNotWord
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
}
```

What I have so far is this,

```
var aspectFields = getAspectFieldIDs().Where(fieldID => fieldID > 0).ToList();//retrieves a list of AspectFieldID's that match user input
var result = db.Aspects
    .Where(p => aspectFields.Contains(p.AspectFieldID))
    .ToList();
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: `Here are my objects` this doesn't make any sense. You aren't using Entity Framework if your objects aren't in the database.

Comment: Sorry @Aron, the objects holding words are not in the database. They are from user input. The `Aspect` object is in the database. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me say, if this is your requirement... your query will read every record in the database.  This is going to be a slow operation.

```
IQueryable<Aspect> query = db.Aspects.AsQueryable();

  //note, if AllWords is empty, query is not modified.
foreach(SearchAllWord x in AllWords)
{
  //important, lambda should capture local variable instead of loop variable.
  string word = x.Word; 
  query = query.Where(aspect => aspect.Value.Contains(word);
}

foreach(SearchNotWord x in NotWords)
{
  string word = x.Word;
  query = query.Where(aspect => !aspect.Value.Contains(word);
}

if (AnyWords.Any()) //haha!
{
  List<string> words = AnyWords.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
  query =
    from aspect in query
    from word in words  //does this work in EF?
    where aspect.Value.Contains(word)
    group aspect by aspect into g
    select g.Key;
}
```

---

If you're sending this query into Sql Server, be aware of the ~2100 parameter limit.  Each word is going to be sent as a parameter.

Comment: I am having troubles with that 'by'. It is saying "Invalid Expression term 'by'". and I definitely understand it will take a long time, haha, any better solutions? This table is expected to get quite large.

Comment: @DavidB - The inefficiency you mention is more a shortcoming of EF than Linq. I can do this with Linq2sql in ways that are expressed as index scans.

Comment: @PeterWone Index scans are table scans. The issue here is that `string.contains` cannot be done in any way more efficient than O(n) (except using Full Text Search).

Comment: @JohZant updated the group clause... see if that works.  If you're searching from less than ~10000 rows, just pull them into memory and run your query against the list - it could be much faster than having the database parse and parse.

Comment: @PeterWone as Aron mentioned, if every string in the index must be read, that's going to take a lot of time.  Also, I would use my OrTheseFiltersTogether method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14557250/8155 but I've been told EF does not support it.

Comment: @DavidB This table will build up over time as Users create more "Aspects". We are expecting over 10000 rows in a few months.

Comment: @Aron index scans can be _of ranges_ with the bounds being found using an index. Also, aspectFieldIds is a _list_ not a string so I'm not sure your interpretation of Contains is correct.

Comment: @JohZant - Given you expect a lot of data soon, frankly I'd give serious thought to Aron's mention of FTI. This can give you high performance ranked strength of match on big data for surprisingly little bother. With no disrespect intended you will do better standing on the shoulders of giants than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @PeterWone, thanks for the advice. I think I am going to look into that now.

Answer (score 0):

What you need are the set operators, specifically

- Intersect
- Any

Bundle up your "all" words into a string array (or some other enumerable) and then you can use intersect and count to check they are all present.

Here are two sets

```
var A = new string[] { "first", "second", "third" };
var B = new string[] { "second", "third" };
```

A is a superset of B?

```
var isSuperset = A.Intersect(B).Count() == B.Count();
```

A is disjoint with B?

```
var isDisjoint1 = !A.Intersect(B).Any();
var isDisjoint2 = !A.Any(a => B.Any(b => a == b)); //faster
```

Your objects are not strings so you will want the [overload that allows you to supply a comparator function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

And now some soapboxing.

Much as I love Linq2sql it is not available in ASP.NET Core and the EF team wants to keep it that way, probably because jerks like me keep saying "gross inefficiency X of EF doesn't apply to Linq2Sql".

Core is the future. Small, fast and cross platform, it lets you serve a Web API from a Raspberry Pi running Windows IOT *or Linux* -- or get ridiculously high performance on big hardware.

EF is not and probably never will be a high performance proposition because it takes control away from you while insisting on being platform agnostic, which prevents it from exploiting the platform.

In the absence of Linq2sql, the solution seems to be libraries like Dapper, which handle parameters when sending the query and map results into object graphs when the result arrives, but otherwise don't do much. This makes them more or less platform agnostic but still lets you exploit the platform - apart from parameter substitution your SQL is passthrough.

Comment: I might be reading into this a little bit, but I don't think that Aspect.Value is a single word.  Due to this, the solution needs more than exact matching.

Comment: @DavidB, you are correct! This can be a sentence. Yes, I am aware that I could have named the variable a little better. Might look at doing this after this gets solved. haha.

Comment: The value I am trying to provide is a brief introduction to set comparison using Linq. And some anti-EF soapboxing :)

Comment: "platform agnostic, which prevents it from exploiting the platform" Pray tell, how passing every string to the database in `nvarchar` and breaking all `varchar`/`char` indices, makes Linq2SQL agnostic?

Comment: @PeterWone That is a Linq2SQL issue not present in EF actually. L2S is a C# team product, not a ADO.Net product.

Comment: @Aron - So it is, I misread you. Linq2sql does not claim platform independence and you are right about the bug, I have discussed it elsewhere at length.